# Test of randomization of non-repeating numbers sample

Tags: spss, random-generation

I have a sample of non-repeating numbers 45...18024. The numbers are supposed to be distributed in a random order. How can I check the strength of randomization? Which tests in SPSS can I use to ensure their randomness?

Comment: Please explain what a "non-repeating number" is.

Comment: @whuber "non-repeated numbers", obviously...

Comment: Many tests could be proposed, depending on the alternative you consider— what makes you think that they may not be not randomly shuffled? Do you think for example that, while not perfectly sorted, they tend to be increasing? Or that numbers with lots of divisors come first, prime number come last? You need to tell us more about the situation which leads to this question.

Comment: I think any sequence of numbers can be called "random", even 45, 46, 47, 48..18024

Comment: I should make  a rlinear regression between the sequence of 45...18024 and my random sample

Comment: @Elvis Vague characterizations like "non-repeating" tend to be "obvious" only when one's experience includes no other alternatives.  For instance, "45" and "18024" might be "non-repeating numbers" while "99" and "12304567891" are not, because *they each contain a digit more than once.*  It's not hard to conceive of other possible meanings, too.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I mean every number occurs only once in a sample. The sample is a shuffled sequence of whole numbers from 45 to 18024.

Answer (score 2):

I think a [Wald-Wolfowitz runs test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) would be adequate here. I do not know about SPSS, but chances are that this test will be available in that package, as is in many others.

Comment: According to the wikipedia page you link, this test is for two-valued sequences. There’s an advice for the general case, which is to replace values below the median by -1 and values above by +1, but it seems to me that much information is lost here...

Comment: Yes, that is true. A less wasteful possibility would be to write the sequence of numbers in binary and apply the test to the resulting sequence of 0's and 1's.  As I understand, the numbers considered here are integers. However, even the rough test of runs of above-the-median and  below-the-median may help to uncover some non-randomness and may be as much as is practical in SPSS.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the remarks, there are many possibilities. F. Tusell proposed a solution, you may also run the Wald-Wolfowitz test on the sign of the differences between successive terms.

I’ll try to propose something funny. It’s only approximate but I wanted to see how it behaves.

I consider a random ordering $X_1, \dots, X_n$ of $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ (you can always go back to this situation, e.g. relabeling your numbers in increasing order). I let $Y_i = X_{i+1} - X_i$ for $i= 1, \dots, n-1$.

Under the hypothesis of a random ordering, the $Y_i$ are identically distributed, but not independent. I’ll make the assumption that if $n$ is large, it does not matter much.

Let $\kappa = n(n-1)$. The law of each of the $Y_i$'s is given by
$$ \begin{aligned} 
Pr( Y = n-1 ) = Pr(Y = 1-n) &= {1 \over \kappa} \\
Pr( Y = n-2 ) = Pr(Y = 2-n) &= {2 \over \kappa} \\
\vdots \\
Pr( Y = 1 ) = Pr(Y = -1) &= {n-1 \over \kappa}
\end{aligned}$$

D’où une cdf 
$$ F(y) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle {1 \over 2 \kappa} (n+y)(n+y+1) & \text{if } y < 0 \\
\displaystyle 1 - {1 \over 2 \kappa} (n-y-1)(n-y) & \text{if } y \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

We will compare the empirical cdf obtained from the $Y_i$'s to the cdf (here we neglect the non-independence of the $Y_i$'s).

Here are two graphs to have a first look.

```
cdf <- function(y, n) {
  k <- n*(n-1);
  y <- floor(y);
  ifelse(y < -(n-1), 0,
    ifelse(y > n-1, 1,
      ifelse(y < 0, (n+y)*(n+y+1), 2*k-(n-y-1)*(n-y))/(2*k)
    )
  )
}

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
set.seed(1)
f <- ecdf( diff(sample.int(25)) )
t <- seq(-26, 26, length=1001)
plot(t, f(t), type="l")
lines(t, cdf(t,25), col="red")

f <- ecdf( diff(sample.int(100)) )
t <- seq(-100, 100, length=1001)
plot(t, f(t), type="l")
lines(t, cdf(t,100), col="red")
```

[image]

This looks promising. However the experiments show that Kolmogrov-Smirnov is overly conservative! Is this because the dependency between the $Y_i$ produces a too good fit -- or is that because the distribution is not continuous?

The obvious solution is too use a Monte-Carlo method to get the empirical distribution of a deviance statistic... It can be computed as this.

```
stat <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  f <- ecdf( diff(x) )
  a <- seq(-n,n)
  max( abs(f(a) - cdf(a,n)) )
}
```

So let's compute e.g. 10,000 values under the null.

```
> D <- replicate(1e4, stat( sample.int(1000) ))
```

[image]

Compare with an imperfectly shuffled sample:

```
> stat(  c(sample(1:500),sample(501:1000)))
[1] 0.1755706
```

It was fun.